# Magento 2: Retrieving and updating Attribute Options and Store Lables

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, attributes, stores, attribute-options

I am currently trying to update an attribute options store label and facing some issues. I can successfully update option store labels by calling

```
$storeLables = [];
$optionLabel = $this->optionLabelFactory->create();
$optionLabel->setStoreId(1);
$optionLabel->setLabel("Test");
$storeLables[] = $optionLabel;

$optionLabel = $this->optionLabelFactory->create();
$optionLabel->setStoreId(2);
$optionLabel->setLabel("Test 2");
$storeLables[] = $optionLabel;

$option->setStoreLabels($storeLables);
```

And this works, however lets say in my example above I have 3 store views with the following ids: 1,2,3. Using the code above any label value that was already saved against the option for store 3 would be wiped out. I assume that this is because `setStoreLabels()` replaces the existing array of values for all stores and does not just update the ones that are passed in.

To be able to fix this issue I would need to retrieve the current store labels array and update the ones that I need to and then pass that array to `setStoreLables()`. So my query is, how do I retrieve the store labels for options? I have tried the following:

```
$option->getStoreLabels()
$option->getData('store_labels');
```

However they both return null.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you. Did you manage to find a solution to this since I see it's been 2 months since you asked?